# Linear algebra-onto mapping

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

I've been struggling with this question.

> Let $T:(x,y,z) \mapsto (x,0)$. Why is this transformation not onto?

Since $x$ can be any number, $y$ can only be zero, and we don't care about $z$, then there are infinite possible answers to transform $(x,y,z)$ to $(x,0)$, and therefore it should be onto, right?

Comment: What point is mapped to $(0,1)$, for example?

Comment: @geetha290krm I know there's not a point mapped to (0,1),  but there are many answers for this transformation, right? like (1,0,0) to (1,0), or (2,0,1) to (2,0), so I think this still follows the definition of onto?

Comment: You should edit your question to include the precise definition of "onto" which you are using.